# Displaying a welcome message if a cookie is set

Tags: javascript, cookies

I was trying to make a simple program that displays a welcome message if a cookie is set and if the cookie is not set it will display a prompt box, asking for the user name.

It doesn't work and I don't understand why. Can anyone tell me where is the problem in the code?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays){
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    if(expiredays==null)
        document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) +"";
    else
        document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ";expires="
        +exdate.toGMTString());
}

function getCookie(c_name){
    if(document.cookie.length>0)
    {

        c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if(c_start!=-1)
            c_start=c_start + c_name.length +1;
            //index of the value's end 
            c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
            if(c_end==-1)//if it's the last cookie
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            return unescape (document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie(){
    username=getCookie('username');
    if(username!=null && username!="")
        alert('welcome again ' + username+ '!');
    else {
        username=prompt('please enter your name:',"");
        if(username!=null && username!="")
            setCookie('username',username,365);
        }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/AcanusA/12/edit

Comment: have you checked out the jsbin-tab "console" ? "Unexpected token )","checkCookie is not defined"

Comment: why are you saying that checkCookies is not defined?

Comment: @Shiran The console says that!

Comment: right.. I wasn't looking at it..

Comment: @Shiran Are you serious? So you decided to post a question here without even looking at the console? That makes me sad...

Comment: Sorry for making you sad @MarcusEkwall .. I wasn't aware of the console.. normally I only use the notepad++ where there is no console.. :-) But I ll look at it from now.

Answer (score 3):

There're two errors in your code. One unclosed ")" (in `setCookie()` function just after last `toGMTString();`) and one unclosed "}" (in `getCookie()` function, just after `if(c_start!=-1){`).

Just take a look in your javascript console to check this errors. Here's the correction:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays){
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    if(expiredays==null)
        document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) +"";
    else
        document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ";expires="
        +exdate.toGMTString();
}

function getCookie(c_name){
    if(document.cookie.length>0)
    {

        c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
      if(c_start!=-1){
            c_start=c_start + c_name.length +1;
            //index of the value's end 
            c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
            if(c_end==-1)//if it's the last cookie
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            return unescape (document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie(){
    username=getCookie('username');
    if(username!=null && username!="")
        alert('welcome again ' + username+ '!');
    else {
        username=prompt('please enter your name:',"");
        if(username!=null && username!="")
            setCookie('username',username,365);
        }
}
</script>
</head>
  <body onload="checkCookie()">
    za
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep, I deleted it hehe

Answer (score 1):

Here's an optimized version of your code:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var setPos = document.cookie.indexOf(name + '='), stopPos = document.cookie.indexOf(';', setPos);
    return !~setPos ? null : document.cookie.substring(
        setPos, ~stopPos ? stopPos : undefined).split('=')[1];
}

function setCookie(name, val, days, path) {
    var cookie = name + "=" +  escape(val) + "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        cookie += ";expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    cookie += ";" + (path || "path=/");
    console.log(cookie);
    document.cookie = cookie;
}

var username = getCookie("username");
if (!username) {
    setCookie("username", prompt("please enter your name:"), 365);
} else {
    alert("welcome again " + username);
}
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7r9XH/).